# HiveError: Box not found error on hot restart or build in Flutter

Tags: flutter, local-storage, flutter-hive

I have this code which starts the app build in error but when hot reloaded app works again if I hot restart error occurs again .I have initialized the Box and app works just fine after hot reload but not hot restart or if built in debug mode.

main

```
void main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();

  Hive.openBox('mybox');
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

HomePage.dart

```
 class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
      final _myBox = Hive.box('mybox');


void writeData() {
      if (_keyText.text.isEmpty || _valueText.text.isEmpty) {
        if (_keyText.text.isEmpty) {
          result = 'Key cannot be null';
          _keyTextNode.requestFocus();
        } else {
          result = 'Value cannot be null';
          _valueTextNode.requestFocus();
        }
      } else {
        _myBox.put(_keyText.text, _valueText.text);
        result =
            '${_keyText.text} : ${_valueText.text} has been saved to HiveBox';
        emptyTextFields();
      }

      setState(() {
        result = result;
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `openBox` is asynchronous, you need to wait for the box until it's opened before you use it, add `await`:

```
 void main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  await Hive.openBox('mybox'); // add await
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 void main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();//add this line to 
 //ensure Initialized
 await Hive.initFlutter();
 await Hive.openBox('mybox');
 runApp(MyApp());
 }
```

[WidgetsFlutterBinding](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsFlutterBinding-class.html)